# Forward foo:8080 to localhost:8081 while keeping localhost:8080 available

Tags: network, pfctl

To emulate the CI integration testing environment for the application that I’m working with, I want to be able to have the following mapping of requests happen:

- foo:8080 ⟶ localhost:8081
- bar:8080 ⟶ localhost:8080

Without the port change, I can do this easily enough by editing `/etc/hosts`¹ to define foo and bar to be 127.0.0.1, but the port forwarding has me stumped. Is this possible with `pf` and if so, how? I’ve found recipes that would map *all* requests to port 8080 to a different port, but I only want it remapped if it’s a specific hostname.

---

1. I have a vague recollection that Network Utility used to provide this capability but it is now deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

One method would be to create alias IP addresses on the localhost interface as `root`

```
ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.10  0xff000000
ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.100 0xff000000
```

and then define `foo` and `bar` as appropriate in `/etc/hosts` or a
local DNS server

```
127.0.0.10 foo
127.0.0.100 bar
```

and then requests involving the one IP address or the other can likely
be redirected as need be, or they could be used directly if the software only listens on the specific IP address involved.

(There are several such IP addresses available; `127.0.0.0/8` is pretty big.)

Comment: I was thinking of something like this. One note though: I'm pretty sure aliases don't survive reboots, so you'd probably have to create something like a LaunchDaemon to recreate the alias(es) after each startup.

Comment: @GordonDavisson they do not but a `LaunchDaemon` or an `@reboot` cronjob or some `fire-up-the-test-environment` script could handle that.